# Why indexed column is scanned if it is not in select, join or where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have two tables, `GRN` and `GRNStones`.

`GRN` table has:

```
code(PK) Clustered index
GRNType(FK) Non Clustered Index
location (FK)
LocationCode(FK) Non Clustered Index
```

I have written query which is given below. From this query if I look at the execution plan it shows an index scan(non clustered) on `GRNType` column. I have not used this column in `select`, `join` or `where` but is still used. Why?

Query:

```
SELECT  [Code]          = B.Code,
        [InternalParty] = B.InternalParty
FROM GRN A
  INNER JOIN GRNStones B
    ON B.GRNCode = A.Code
WHERE B.Code > 100
```

Execution Plan:

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the entire `create table` scripts for both tables to your question?  Do this from SSMS so it included all the indexes etc.

Comment: Is there a common column between the clustered and non-clustered index? I just ran into a similar problem last week.